# Binding text box to telerik upload control MVC3

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, upload, textbox, telerik

I want my textbox to display the name of file selected by telerik upload control. Please find the code snippet below.

```
<td>
@Html.TextBox(txtBox, null, new { style = string.Format("width:200px") })
</td>
<td style="padding-top: 1%; padding-left: 8%">
@(Html.Telerik().Upload().Name(BrowseButton)
//.HtmlAttributes(new { @class = "myCustomClass" }).Multiple(false))
```

Currently the textbox is displaying null.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Telerik control should allow you to show the file name.  Your extra textbox seems redundant.

Read the [telerik documentation](http://www.telerik.com/help/aspnet-mvc/telerik-ui-components-upload-introduction.html) and specifically the [html and css section](http://www.telerik.com/help/aspnet-mvc/telerik-ui-components-upload-html-output-and-css-styles.html).  It says the following:

During and after uploading, a file list is displayed, which shows the progress and status of each uploaded file. Its HTML output is the following:

```
<ul class="t-upload-files t-reset">
    <li class="t-file">
        <span class="t-icon t-success">uploaded</span>
        <span class="t-filename">some-uploaded-file.jpg</span>
        <button class="t-button t-button-icontext t-upload-action" type="button">
                 <span class="t-icon t-delete"></span>Remove</button>
    </li>
    <li class="t-file">
        <span class="t-icon t-fail">failed</span>
        <span class="t-filename">some-failed-file.jpg
            <span class="t-progress">
         <span style="width: 75%;" class="t-progress-status">
            </span></span>
        </span>
        <button class="t-button t-button-icontext t-upload-action" type="button">
                    <span class="t-icon t-retry"></span>Retry</button>
    </li>
</ul>
```

If you want to update a textbox of your own, simply use their client api by adding this when creating telerik control

```
@(Html.Telerik().Upload().Name(BrowseButton)
.ClientEvents(events => events.OnSelect("onSelect"))
```

and in your javascript

```
function onSelect(e) {
        // Array with information about the uploaded files
        $('#yourTextboxId').val(e.files[0].name);  
    }
```

Again all the details are in the [documentation](http://www.telerik.com/help/aspnet-mvc/telerik-ui-components-upload-client-api-and-events.html#Files).

Comment: i agree that the file name is displayed below the control. However i just want to display that file name in the adjoining textbox. Is there a way i can achieve that.

Comment: @user1737742 you're welcome and thanks for accepting answer. I see you've only joined today, so I don't feel suggesting that it's customary to also upvote an answer you find useful, just above where you accepted answer.  Votes are what makes the SO work.